# data.site.siteMetadata.description is missing props validation - gatsby and graphQl

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, gatsby

I'm trying to render the site's metadata from graphql query, the query runs fine in graphql playground but I cant even seem to console.log the data, when I try to log it out, it gives me an integer in the console?
So instead I just tried to render it on the screen using the gatsby docs and got this error:  32:41  error  'data.site.siteMetadata.description' is missing in props validation

```js
const IndexPage = ({ data }) => {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <SEO
        keywords={[`gatsby`, `tailwind`, `react`, `tailwindcss`]}
        title="Home"
      />
      <div className="container mx-auto flex flex-col md:flex-row items-center">
        <div className="flex flex-col w-full lg:w-1/2 justify-center items-start pt-12 pb-24 lg:-px-12">
          <h3
            style={{ fontFamily: "Permanent Marker" }}
            className="text-4xl py-2 lg:-mx-32 font-title"
          >
            Meet the world’s only dedicated analytic platform for active
            nutrition.
          </h3>
          <h4
            style={{ fontFamily: "Montserrat" }}
            className="text-2xl py-10 lg:relative right-32"
          >
            Nutrition Integrated supplies companies with the data, tools and
            insights to understand the moving landscape and make smarter
            decisions.
          </h4>
        </div>
        <div className="w-full lg:w-hero lg:py-6 text-center lg:-mr-12 relative lg:left-24">
          <img
            className="fill-current text-black  "
            src={image}
            alt="image"
          ></img>
        </div>
        <h2> {data.site.siteMetadata.description}</h2>
      </div>
    </Layout>
  );
};

export const query = graphql`
  query MyQuery {
    allContentfulLandingPage {
edges {
  node {
    heroTitle {
      heroTitle
    }
    heroBody {
      raw
    }
  }  
}
  }
  }
`;

export default IndexPage;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This message appears because you are using [`PropTypes`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prop-types) to validate your `props` types. Basically, it's a validation of the type of data you are drilling through `props`, which enhances the cohesion of your code.

For example, if you are expecting a boolean somewhere, the type of property will be boolean. If later in the future you or any teammate changes it to a string, the validation will fail because the type is not defined. Generally, it prompts the issue in the browser's console. In your case, because you are not defining the type, it fails.

The structure looks like:

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const YourComponent = ({ name })=> {
    return (
      <h1>Hello, {this.props.name}</h1>
    );
}

YourComponent.propTypes = {
  name: PropTypes.string
};
```

That said, you can:

- Remove the `PropType` validation: just remove the import:

  ```
  import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
  ```
- Provide a prop validation: add the type of the shapes of `data`. Because `data` is an object, it's a little bit more complex than the previous example but it should look like:

  ```
  YourComponent.propTypes = {
        data: PropTypes.shape({
          site: PropTypes.shape({
            siteMetadata: PropTypes.shape({
              description: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
            }).isRequired,
          }).isRequired,
        }).isRequired,
      };
  ```

  Depending on your scenario, you may want to remove the `isRequired` attribute.

Given:

```
export const query = graphql`
  query MyQuery {
    allContentfulLandingPage {
      edges {
        node {
          heroTitle {
            heroTitle
          }
          heroBody {
            raw
          }
        }  
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

The `PropTypes` should look like:

```
   IndexPage.propTypes = {
        data: PropTypes.shape({
          edges: PropTypes.shape({
            node: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.object)
          }).isRequired,
        }).isRequired,
      };
```

I'm not sure what you are getting in `raw`, so I've wrapped inside `PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.object)`. [Check the types](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html) and change them accordingly.

Comment: I've added a snippet (`YourComponent)` demonstrating how. You just need to put it wherever you use `PropTypes` (I guess in your `IndexPage` but you haven't share it all)

Comment: hi, ive edited the question, can you show me how I would customize the propTyes for this query?

Comment: Answer edited. Check https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html for more details